# How can I check on which Facebook account user is logged-in in their PC, to update the respective token for that Facebook User

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-apps, django-allauth, facebook-ads-api

I created an application in python using allauth with the facebook provider, which have the posibility to allow to add multiple Facebook Account.
For updating the token, user needs to re-add their Facebook Account.
Suppose that we have a user with two different facebook accounts; Facebook UserA and Facebook UserB.

How can I check on which Facebook account user is logged-in  in their PC, to update the respective token for that Facebook User.

Or any idea how can i check that?

Comment: a user can only have one account, so what´s the point?

Comment: @luschn a user can have one account on my application, but he can add multiple facebook accounts. For example (their personal facebook account and another facebook account that use for business or another)

Comment: facebook only allowes one user profile per user. there can be no business or other accounts.

Comment: @luschn i understand that.. Do you have any idea how can I check on which Facebook account user is logged-in in their PC? Its possible?

Comment: i am not sure what the question is, to be honest. there is a user, make sure he is logged in on your app, use his user token for a call to /me to get his id and name, that´s it. but again, only ONE user is allowed, and we will certainly not help you do something that is not allowed. ;)

Comment: I believe the author is asking how to check from a web app what user is logged in Facebook (if it's possible).